# Best way to secure local drives on dual boot workstation

Tags: windows-10, security, ubuntu-18.04, device-manager

At a customer's I have a workstation with dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.

Given that someone needs admin rights on Windows, and another one needs a sudoer user in Linux I decided to enable disk level encryption. Ubuntu has been installed with "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" option enabled. In Windows 10 the Bitlocker feature has been turned on.

After setting up grub as default boot loader and booting the newly created Windows 10 entry I had to type the Bitlocker key (only once) in order to decrypt the disk and boot Windows.

This way I was able to prevent each privileged user from both systems to access the other's.

Anyway, I'm still concerned about the fact that, either by mistake or maliciously, one of them will still be able to `diskpart/clean` the Ubuntu disk from Windows or `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` the Windows disk from Linux.

Reducing their access level to the system is unfortunately not applicable here, so I was wondering if there is any "effective" hack I could implement in both systems in order to effectively hide the unused encrypted disk from device managers.

Comment: You can't access a Linux partition on Windows without extra software if I'm correct.

Comment: So you are looking for ways, to prevent elevated users, from wiping unmounted disks?

Comment: Hiding those devices to prevent all the "human mistakes part". And maybe even some automated or not-so-skilled malicious one.